# When to prefer `and` over `andalso` in guard tests

Tags: erlang, short-circuiting, boolean-expression

I am curious why the comma ‹,› is a shortcut for `and` and not `andalso` in guard tests.

Since I'd call myself a “C native” I fail to see any shortcomings of short-circuit boolean evaluation.

I compiled some test code using the `to_core` flag to see what code is actually generated. Using the comma, I see the left hand value and right and value get evaluated and both and'ed. With `andalso` you have a case block within the case block and no call to `erlang:and/2`.

I did no benchmark tests but I daresay the `andalso` variant is the faster one.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To delve into the past:

- Originally in guards there were only `,` separated *tests* which were evaluated from left-to-right until either there were no more and the guard succeeded or a test failed and the guard as a whole failed. Later `;` was added to allow alternate guards in the same clause. If guards evaluate both sides of a `,` before testing then someone has gotten it wrong along the way. @Kay's example seems to imply that they do go from left-to-right as they should.
- Boolean operators were only allowed much later in guards.
- `and`, together with `or`, `xor` and `not`, is a boolean operator and was not intended for control. They are all *strict* and evaluate their arguments first, like the arithmetic operators `+`, `-`, `*` and '/'. There exist strict boolean operators in C as well.
- The short-circuiting *control* operators `andalso` and `orelse` were added later to simplify some code. As you have said the compiler does expand them to nested `case` expressions so there is no performance gain in using them, just convenience and clarity of code. This would explain the resultant code you saw.
- **N.B.** in guards there are *tests* and not expressions. There is a subtle difference which means that while using `and` and `andalso` is equivalent to `,` using `orelse` is not equivalent to `;`. This is left to another question. Hint: it's all about failure.

So both `and` and `andalso` have their place.

Answer (score 8):

Adam Lindbergs [link](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0017.html) is right. Using the comma does generate better beam code than using andalso. I compiled the following code using the +to_asm flag:

```
a(A,B) ->
    case ok of
        _ when A, B -> true;
        _ -> false
    end.
aa(A,B) ->
    case ok of
        _ when A andalso B -> true;
        _ -> false
    end.
```

which generates

```
{function, a, 2, 2}.
  {label,1}.
    {func_info,{atom,andAndAndalso},{atom,a},2}.
  {label,2}.
    {test,is_eq_exact,{f,3},[{x,0},{atom,true}]}.
    {test,is_eq_exact,{f,3},[{x,1},{atom,true}]}.
    {move,{atom,true},{x,0}}.
    return.
  {label,3}.
    {move,{atom,false},{x,0}}.
    return.

{function, aa, 2, 5}.
  {label,4}.
    {func_info,{atom,andAndAndalso},{atom,aa},2}.
  {label,5}.
    {test,is_atom,{f,7},[{x,0}]}.
    {select_val,{x,0},{f,7},{list,[{atom,true},{f,6},{atom,false},{f,9}]}}.
  {label,6}.
    {move,{x,1},{x,2}}.
    {jump,{f,8}}.
  {label,7}.
    {move,{x,0},{x,2}}.
  {label,8}.
    {test,is_eq_exact,{f,9},[{x,2},{atom,true}]}.
    {move,{atom,true},{x,0}}.
    return.
  {label,9}.
    {move,{atom,false},{x,0}}.
    return.
```

I only looked into what is generated with the +to_core flag, but obviously there is a optimization step between to_core and to_asm.

Answer (score 5):

It's an historical reason. `and` was implemented before `andalso`, which was introduced in Erlang 5.1 (the only reference I can find right now is [EEP-17](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0017.html)). Guards have not been changed because of backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 5):

The boolean operators "**and**" and "**or**" always evaluate arguements on both the sides of the operator. Whereas if you want the functionality of C operators **&&** and **||** (where 2nd arguement is evaluated only if needed..for eg if we want to evalue "true **orelse** false" as soon as true is found to be the first arguement, the second arguement will not be evaluated which is not the case had "**or**" been used ) go for "**andalso**" and "**orelse**".