# What is the use of non short-circuiting boolean operators in Erlang?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, erlang, logic-programming

I am learning Erlang from the LearnYouSomeErlang web-book. One thing that struck me while learning was the non short-circuiting boolean conjunction and disjunction operators viz; `and` and `or`. What are the use cases for these operators? Why would you want to use them instead of `andalso` and `orelse`?

Comment: Tagged with `Logic Programming` because I was told that this has something to do with Erlang's origins in Prolog.

Comment: Related: [When to prefer `and` over `andalso` in guard tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025132/when-to-prefer-and-over-andalso-in-guard-tests).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It used to be (until R13A) that `andalso` and `orelse` weren't tail recursive. See http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0017.html for details. I don't think there is a good reason to use `and`/`or` in *new* programs.

Comment: Interesting link. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

I see them as doing different things and use them as such:

- `and`/`or` as logical operators where I want to compare the logical values. As they are strict I automatically get type-checking and I **KNOW** exactly what has been called.
- `andalso`/`orelse` for control, much like `&&` and `||` in C.

Seeing errors are defined in erlang I feel it is good to know what has been executed and how it went.

Comment: 1. `andalso` and `orelse` can also be used as logical operators. 2. I didn't understand the bit about type-checking. 3. Knowing what has been called shouldn't matter with referentially transparent expressions; it is only relevant in the context of side-effects.

Comment: I think what Robert is saying is that sometimes you want all operands to be evaluated so that they can raise exceptions, even if they are not necessary for the evaluation of the predicate.  It's a good point.

Comment: @dsmith: Yes, both that and to check that they actually return boolean values. I am perhaps being overly cautious but it is good to catch errors as early as possible.

Answer (score 4):

The and/or operators are simply much older. The andalso/orelse operators are later additions. A use case for and/or today could be when you just want to perform some simple boolean operations and horizontal space is more important than possibly saving a couple of machine cycles. For example:

```
X = Y and (A or B),
```

rather than

```
X = Y andalso (A orelse B),
```

is a bit easier on the eyes.

For reasons of backwards compatibility, it wasn't possible to just change the behaviour of the original and/or to become short-circuiting, so new keywords were needed. The names andalso/orelse come from Standard ML.